# Merge muti-website into single website in magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, multistore, magento2.4.2, multi-website, multidomain

I want to merge two stores into a single store in Magento 2.4. Can anyone have an idea about it and what steps need to be taken before merging?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: what you mean by merge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now done.
For more clarification about my question suppose there are two websites abc.com and xyz.com, I want to close the website xyz.com, so I need to transfer all the data like customers, orders, and products to abc.com from xyz.com. So, I have done this by custom scripts for all the entities.

Here is the script for orders for example.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include 'app/bootstrap.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();

function _mpLog($data, $includeSep = false)
{
    $fileName = BP . '/var/log/salesordergridpreviousstore.log';
    if ($includeSep) {
        $separator = str_repeat('=', 70);
        file_put_contents($fileName, $separator . '<br />' . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
    file_put_contents($fileName, $data . '<br />' . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}

function mpLogAndPrint($message, $separator = false)
{
    _mpLog($message, $separator);
    if (is_array($message) || is_object($message)) {
        print_r($message);
    } else {
        echo $message . '<br />' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    if ($separator) {
        echo str_repeat('=', 70) . '<br />' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
function _getResourceConnection()
{
    global $objectManager;
    return $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
}

function _getReadConnection()
{
    return _getConnection('core_read');
}

function _getWriteConnection()
{
    return _getConnection('core_write');
}

function _getConnection($type = 'core_read')
{
    return _getResourceConnection()->getConnection($type);
}

function updateSalesOrderPreviousStore($storeId,$entityId)
{
    $connection = _getWriteConnection();
    if($storeId==1){
        $sql = "UPDATE " . 'sales_order_grid' . " SET previous_store_so=".'"Main Website"'. " where entity_id=" . $entityId;
        $connection->query($sql);
    }elseif($storeId==2){
        $sql = "UPDATE " . 'sales_order_grid' . " SET previous_store_so=".'"Old Store"'. " where entity_id=" . $entityId;
        $connection->query($sql);
    }
}

try {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($order as $value) {
        $count++;
        $storeid=$value->getStoreId();
        $entityid=$value->getEntityId();
        $incrementid=$value->getIncrementId();
        try {
            updateSalesOrderPreviousStore($storeid,$entityid);
            if($storeid==1){
                $store = "Main Website";
            }elseif($storeid==2){
                $store = "Old Store";
            }
            $message = $count . '. SUCCESS:: Updated Sales Order Grid with Previous Store (' . $store . ') for order id (' . $entityid . ') and increment id (' . $incrementid . ')';
            mpLogAndPrint($message);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $message = $count . '. ERROR:: While updating  Sales Order Grid  for order id (' . $entityid . ') and increment id (' . $incrementid . ') => ' . $e->getMessage();
            mpLogAndPrint($message);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    mpLogAndPrint(
        'EXCEPTION::' . $e->getTraceAsString()
    );
}
```

In these, I have created new order attribute previous_store_so, and stored the old store value in that. After adding it just need to run the following queries in the DB table.

> UPDATE `sales_order` SET `store_id` = 1 WHERE `store_id` = 2;
>
> UPDATE `sales_order_grid` SET `store_id` = 1 WHERE `store_id` = 2;

Comment: Please post your script as an answer here which helps others.

Comment: Updated the answer.